# Error 'ssl peer certificate or SSH remote key was not ok' connecting to snowflake through RODBC

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rodbc

I'm trying to access the snowflake database through R using the RODBC package.
When I run queries using the sqlQuery function, it just returns the error above, with

```
failed:CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
```

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: This may be an OCSP check problem. Please read here on why that can happen and optionally override the default behavior: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html

Comment: Agree with Greg that it could be OCSP and potential whitelisting issue.  You may need assistance from your network engineering team to make sure the traffic is not being intercepted or blocked.